# Heroku doesn't load precompiled assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, assets

I have a staging server on Heroku with the same code pushed to it as my production server (also on Heroku) and none of the assets load in staging, but they all work in prod. Rails 3.2.11.

The assets:precompile works and I can log in with bash and see all of the assets precompiled under public/assets. But I keep getting 404s when I try to view them.

The logs get a whole lot of this:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/team_accessories_ad.png"):
```

I feel like I've tried just about everything. Even though the files are there, it's not routing to public/assets to get them. Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Thanks

EDIT: In my case it was caused by the 12factor gem (https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor). When I removed this gem, everything started working!

Thanks

Comment: You are linking to the images incorrectly - you need to be using Rails' asset helpers.

Comment: What makes you think that? because the image filename doesn't have a big number at the end? I also get these in the log `heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/logo-8a3a8daaac499c2e20f4c6ef188623a9.png host=<appname>.herokuapp.com fwd="<ip addr>" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=141ms status=404 bytes=1330`

Comment: Yes. If you can provide an example of how you're trying to access these assets, we might be able to actually help.

Comment: Through the browser at `http://<appname>.herokuapp.com/assets/logo.png`, from the app either through `= image_tag "btnBack.png"` or just plain `%img{:src => '/assets/invite.png'}`. Thanks

Comment: the image_tag example will work because that's using a Rails helper which will automatically add the digest, the other two will not.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but none of them are working. And the css and js are 404ing too `https://<appname>.herokuapp.com/assets/theme-51f77eef5b1ac49f7011f2db28301855.css`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your images are not dynamically linked in your asset files:

---

**SCSS**

Rails comes bundled with [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/) because this allows you to precompile the image assets correctly. SCSS is dynamically rendered when you use `rake assets:precompile`, whereas CSS cannot dynamically render the assets

Because [Rails fingerprints the assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark) when they are precompiled, it means that many of the image assets (which will have a name of `XXXX.png` before precompile), will have broken paths after the precompile (makes them `XXX-dsdasdfew5823459432jt342j52435.png`)

The solution is to use dynamic image paths in scss:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/images.css.scss
body {
    background: asset_url('image_path.png')
}
```

This allows you to dynamically render the image path at precompile, giving you the ability to see the image in production

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out to be caused by changes on [how Rails 4 handles static files](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor#rails-4-serve-static-assets). I added rails_12factor gem to my production group and it fixed the issue. I think I could've gotten away by just adding `rails_serve_static_assets` but didn't try that.